# Create directories based on month name

Tags: bash, date, directory, iteration

I'm looking for a way to create the following structure. (starting from a set year, until the current year)

eg :

```
2008
  - January
  - Feburary
  - ...
  - December
2009
  - January
  - Feburary
  - ...
  - December
```

I've got some basic bash skills, but have not figured out the part on how to get the full month names and use those to create these structures.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A straightforward answer:

```
mkdir -p {2008..2013}/{January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December}
```

If the starting year is user-determined, e.g., in a variable:

```
starting_year=2008
current_year=$(date +%Y)
for ((y=starting_year;y<=current_year;++y)); do
    mkdir -p "$y"/{January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December}
done
```